# How to assign radio buttons a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, radiobuttonlist

What I need to do is turn the 4 different values (when clicked) on the page into a number that I can use to calculate the output in the chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/nlem33/eyGMu/7/

```
var min_value = 0,
  max_value = 10,
  units = 0,
  price = 0;
var sliderHandler = function (event, ui) {
  var newdata = [],
    newdata2 = []
    data = [],
    sum = 0;
  if(this.id === 'slider1') {
    $('#slider1_value').html(ui.value);
    units = ui.value;
  } else {
    $('#slider2_value').html('$' + ui.value);
    price = ui.value;
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    data.push(units * price);
    for(var j = 0; j < i; j++)
    sum += data[j];
    newdata.push(229 * units * i);
    newdata2.push(sum);
  }
  console.log(newdata);
  chart.series[0].setData(newdata2);
  chart.series[1].setData(newdata);
}
```

Comment: By 4 values are you talking about the 4 buttons at the bottom: "1000GB", "500GB"... ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Your JSFiddle doesn't have any radio buttons.

Comment: Yep those are those ones I'm talking about!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable called `selected` and use this event handler:

```
var selected = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".product").click(function(){
        selected = this.id.replace("product", "");
        alert(selected);
    });
});
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyGMu/8/). Then you can use the selected variable anywhere.

In order to use the value of a radio button rather than the number in its id, use the following code instead:

```
var selected = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=chooseProduct]").change(function(){
        selected = $(this).val();
        alert(selected);
    });
});
```

See next [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyGMu/12/) for that example as well.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use the value I assign to the radio button as the selected variable?

Comment: I mean the value I assign in the radio button  <input id="1" type="radio" value="229" name="chooseProduct" checked="checked"><label for="1"> 1000GB</label> Thanks for all your help by the way :)

Comment: @user2160685 By that you mean the value 229?

Comment: @user2160685 I have updated the answer to make it more appropriate to radio buttons. Note that the selector and event have changed.